# Running a hideRow/showRows script over multiple sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a job costing sheet for my install crews and need some help with hiding or showing certain rows.

Trying to hide or show certain rows over multiple sheets in google sheets using Apps Script.
It's working in 1 defined sheet called "Job 1".
But for it to be fully functional it needs to do the same over multiple sheet "Job 1", "Job 2", "Job 3",etc...

Below is the code I'm using right now. [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73079540/googlesheet-dropdown-list-to-show-hide-rows)

```
     function onEdit(a) {
      var watchSheet = "Job 1";
      var watchCell = "A33";
      
      var sheet = a.range.getSheet();
      if (sheet.getName() !== watchSheet ||
          a.range.getA1Notation() !== watchCell) {
        return;
      }
      sheet.hideRows(34, 6);
      switch (a.value) {
        case "YES":
          sheet.showRows(34, 6);
          break;
        case "NO":
          sheet.hideRows(34, 6);
          break;
        default:
      }  
    }
```

It needs to hide rows in multiple sheets according to what the dropdown result is in A33 of each sheet individually.

So 
If "Job 1 A33" has NO it needs to hide certain rows in the sheet "Job 1".
If "Job 2 A33" has NO it needs to hide certain rows in the sheet "Job 2".
If "Job 2 A33" has YES it needs to show certain rows in the sheet "Job 3".

Anyways, I would appreciate the help.
Thanks

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And also, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Code from above for Multiple Sheets

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet0"];//sheet names where code will work
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName())
  if (~idx && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 33 && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    sh.hideRows(34, 6);
    if (e.value == "YES") {
      sh.showRows(34, 6);
    } else if (e.value == "NO") {
      sh.hideRows(34, 6);
    }
  }
}
```